# How to correctly use events relating to loading of audio

Tags: javascript, events, audio, event-handling

I'm making an audio player and trying to add functionality such that when any audio element (there are multiple coordinated tracks) hasn't loaded enough data to keep playing, the Play button turns into a loading Button and other audio elements are paused, etc. etc. Then when audio has loaded sufficiently to play, play resumes.

For the latter point, it seems clear enough that there are two relevant event handlers: `canplay` and `canplaythrough`, and I'm clear on the distinction between them.

However, for the former part, the loading, I'm confused which event I should use for my functionality. These all seem to be relevant:

- stalled
- suspend
- waiting

The [W3Schools reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) would suggest that `waiting` is my go-to. (Even though [Mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) has a completely different description of it). But if that's the case, do I need to use any of the others as well, in specific edge cases? If one of those others fires, does `waiting` fire as well?

Then there's also `playing` - should I use that to trigger resuming audio after loading event?

Perhaps someone could provide the barebones code for implementing what I want?

### Edit

Here is some code showing my current setup. As you can see, I'm hedging my bets as to which event might be fired once buffering has completed.

```
// main Player object
function Player() {
    this.playing = false;
    this.waitForLoad = false;

    this.audio = new Audio(filepath);
    this.narration.preload = "auto";
    this.narration.addEventListener('canplaythrough', () => { this.loaded(); });
    this.narration.addEventListener('waiting', () => { this.audioWaiting(); });
    this.narration.addEventListener('playing', () => { this.audioUnwaiting(); });
}

Player.prototype =
{
    play: function() {
        this.playing = true;
        this.narration.play();
        playButton.addClass('pause');
    },

    pause: function() {
        this.playing = false;
        this.narration.pause();
        playButton.removeClass('pause');
    },

    // for onLoaded event
    loaded: function() {
        playButton.removeClass('loading'); // playButton starts off with class="play loading"
        if (this.playing && this.waitForLoad) {
            this.audioUnwaiting();
        }
    },

    // if any element that needs to play now hasn't loaded (or onWaiting events)
    audioWaiting: function() {
        if (!this.waitForLoad) {
            this.waitForLoad = true;
            this.pause();
            playButton.addClass('loading');
        }
    },

    // onPlaying - once an element that needs to play now has loaded
    audioUnwaiting: function() {
        if (this.waitForLoad) {
            this.waitForLoad = false;
            playButton.removeClass('loading');
            if (this.playing) this.play();
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

seems you may be trying to access some read-only properties for your project.  changing icons based on status is no problem with libraries like jquery.

I think 'buffered' is the property that you really want:

[How do I make a loading bar for an HTML5 audio element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025946/how-do-i-make-a-loading-bar-for-an-html5-audio-element)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/buffering_seeking_time_ranges

I think seeing how much has loaded and how far you are already playing in your audio file should be enough information to change the icons and get the functionality you're looking for

I think i need to see what it is you are building to really understand. Do you have a link or something?

Comment: I don't want to poll the elements for how much they've buffered; I'd much rather do it with event handlers, so that they push their state to me and I can react to it. The above list of events suggests there is a whole framework set up for this, it's just unclear how they interact.

Comment: I will try and add some example code to the question soon.